# Checkbox as radio button and add remove values on check Uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to have checkboxes work as radio buttons and at the same add and remove data on check and uncheck respectively.

What I got is working fine when only one checkbox is checked, but not working when I check both. Problem is that after checking 1st checkbox when I check the 2nd box the 1st one is unchecked but the value of 1st is not removed from the list.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uZvMA/

JavaScript:

```
var $unique = $('input.unique');
$unique.click(function() {
    $unique.filter(':checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');

});    

$("#BlackOlives-Half").change(function() {
    // If checked
    var value = $(this).val(),
        $list = $("#itemList");
    if (this.checked) {
        //add to the right
        $list.append("<li data-value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</li>");
    }
    else {
        //hide to the right
        $list.find('li[data-value="' + value + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
$("#BlackOlives-Full").change(function() {
    // If checked
    var value = $(this).val(),
        $list = $("#itemList");
    if (this.checked) {
        //add to the right
        $list.append("<li data-value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</li>");
    }
    else {
        //hide to the right
        $list.find('li[data-value="' + value + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div id="BlackOlives-Half10">Black Olives</div>
        <div class="radioButtons">
        <input type="checkbox" id="BlackOlives-Half" onchange="" class='unique' name="BlackOlives" value="5" /> <label for="BlackOlives-Half">Half</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="BlackOlives-Full" onclick="" class='unique' name="BlackOlives" value="10" /> <label for="BlackOlives-Full">Full</label>
        </div>

    </li>

</ul>
<ul id="itemList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is you are programmatically setting the checked state but it is not firing the change event you need to trigger the change event after. by calling `.trigger('change');`

[have a look at your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvMA/1/)

Comment: Your welcome ! yup, it is also worth noting this keeps your animations unlike the other solution.

Comment: because you did it First... :)

Answer (score 2):

You may not be as interested in this solution now that you have a working one, but I challenged myself to improve upon the initial code a bit. Rather than just calling `change` on everything and be satisfied, I also wanted to make your code **not require nearly 10 additional lines of code per checkbox you would like to support.**

This fiddle includes an extension to jQuery that will enforce uniqueness, retain your animations, and allow reusability (to some extent -- it isn't perfect given that it demands you use an `ul`.)

http://jsfiddle.net/uZvMA/5/

At the very least, please take a look and teach yourself another new thing today :)

**EDIT:** Updated JSFiddle with proof it works in multiple instances. http://jsfiddle.net/uZvMA/6/

Comment: NIce thing ..Multiple instances was good proof.. cheers mate ..+1

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
 $("#itemList").empty();
```

in both your click function

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvMA/3/)**

Comment: Cheers Fahad .. You needed to empty your `ul` before appending new `li`.

Comment: As far as functionality my answer is correct you cant say it wrong .. ..Fahad had not mentioned abt animation ..@yusuf be mature enough ..And let fahad decide the correct answer..

Comment: both of you are correct... hope i could mark both as correct... :) THanks

Comment: @YussufS: what makes you comment `this is incorrect` ?? As per OP its solved the problem, and OP didnt askd for animation, be show some sportmenship rather then greedy of repuation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append, give as html in the BlackOlives-Half and BlackOlives-Full in if condition

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uZvMA/2/)

```
$("#BlackOlives-Half").change(function() {
    // If checked
    var value = $(this).val(),
    $list = $("#itemList");
    if (this.checked) {
         //add to the right
         $list.html("<li data-value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</li>");
    }
    else {
    //hide to the right
    $list.find('li[data-value="' + value + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
});
$("#BlackOlives-Full").change(function() {
    // If checked
    var value = $(this).val(),
    $list = $("#itemList");
    if (this.checked) {
        //add to the right
        $list.html("<li data-value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</li>");
    }
    else {
    //hide to the right
    $list.find('li[data-value="' + value + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: I can't, because there will be more than items at the same time in '$("#itemList");'
Thanks for your response..